# BAD ACCESS error when running SwiftUI app with environment variables

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a simple app with authentication. However, when I run the app, I get a thread one bad access code as shown in the first image. I dont know if it has to do with the environment variable that I've declared, or there is another problem.

I would appreciate any help!

The thread error im getting:

[image]

View with an environment object:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey! Please improve your question, adding the code instead of images, and provide the log message of console.

Comment: Ok sure, sorry for my late reply

Comment: @NanaBonsu please see [ask]

Comment: ok, I will review it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold `AppViewModel` as a `@StateObject` instead of creating it for each view individually each time the app's root view gets rendered:

```
struct VendorHub: App {
    @StateObject var appViewModel = AppViewModel()
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some View {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
                UserSelection()
            }
            .environmentObject(appViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

You have 2 views - `ContentView` and `UserSelection` view. In your code, you assign to each of them a separate instance of `AppViewModel` constructed during the execution of `body`.

Now, to understand where the issue is coming from, you should ask yourself:

- when does the code inside `body` of `VendorHub` and the code inside the body of `ContentView` and `UserSelection` view gets executed?
- is the environment object kept in memory in between these `body` invocations?

To research this, you can implement `deinit` method in `AppViewModel` and log from it when the view model gets deallocated. Also you can log when each body method is executed.

If view model is deallocated in between body invocations, that’s the reason why you get the crash.

That means that you have to keep somehow the instance of view model in between body invocations. That’s where you need `@StateObject`.

Comment: thanks a lot. So does that mean I have to get rid of every EnvironmentObject in all the views

Comment: It's up to you - you can keep it as env object in `ContentView` and `UserSelection` view, and pass it from state in `VendorHub`, or, in those views you can replace `@EnvironmentObject` with `@ObservableObject` and pass `appViewModel` as a parameter to the initializer of those views.

Comment: I updated my answer with more correct use of `@StateObject` instead of `@State` if your minimum iOS version is 14 and above.

Comment: OK thanks. So this should fix that bad access error then? Honestly, I dont even understand where that error is coming from, I think that is another problem I have.

Comment: You tell me :) I pointed you onto the issue in your code and described where the issue is coming from

Comment: Ah I see. So would you recommend a resource I can look into to get a clearer understanding of stateObject and EnvironmentObjects. I think I dont have a clear enough understanding

Comment: I think you just lack the basic understanding of the rendering in SwiftUI. See update on the answer.

Comment: ok thanks, I will look into it. Sorry I replied late.

Comment: Hello Euguene. I have some other questions related to the ios project Im working on. Its not related to this problem. I was wondering if we could connecrt using another medium? I would rally appreciate it